# Communication beetween Javascript and PHP scripts in web app

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, mongodb

### THE CONTEXT

I'm developing a web app that loads contents dynamycally, retrieving data from a 
catalogue of items stored as a MongoDB database in which records of the items and their authors are in two distinct collections of the same database.
Authors ID are stored in the item field **creator** and refer to the author field **@id**.
 Each item can have none,one or many authors.

**Item sample**

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("59f5de430fa594333bb338a6"),
    "@id" : "http://minerva.atcult.it/rdf/000000016009",
    "creator" : "http://minerva.atcult.it/rdf/47734211-2637-3895-a690-4f33412931ec",
    "identifier" : "000000016009",
    "issued" : "fine sec. XIV - inizi sec. XV",
    "title" : "Quadrans vetus",
    "label" : "Quadrans vetus"
    }
```

**Author sample**

```
    {
    "_id" : ObjectId("59f5d8e80fa594333bb1d72c"),
    "@id" : "http://minerva.atcult.it/rdf/0007e43e-107f-3d18-b4bc-89f8d430fe59",
    "@type" : "foaf:Person",
    "name" : "Risse, Wilhelm"
}
```

---

#### WHAT WORKS

I query the database submitting a string in a form, using this PHP script

**ITEM PHP SCRIPT**

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$title=$_GET['item'];
$client = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://localhost:27017");
$db=$client->galileo;
$collection=$db->items;

$regex=new MongoDB\BSON\Regex ('^'.$title,'im');
$documentlist=$collection->find(['title'=>$regex],['projection'=>['_id'=>0,'title'=>1,'creator'=>1,'issued'=>1]]);
$items=$documentlist->toArray();
echo (json_encode($items));


?>
```

called by a Javascript script (**new_search.js**) using ajax, that has also the responsibility to attach to html document a `<li class=item>` for every item that matches the query, inserting the JSON fields and putting them in the provided tags ( `<li class=item-name>`,`<li class=auth-name`, and the last `<li>` in `div class=item-info` for date).

---

#### WHAT DOES NOT WORK

My intent is reproduce the pattern to retrieve author names from another collection in the same database, querying it using author field *@id* from the html tag `<li class=auth-name`, using a similar php script and a similar ajax call.
I tried to make a nested ajax call (in the one I used to retrieve the items infos) to invoke author_query.php that performs the MongoDB query on the collection of authors. 
So, the question is: **Is it possible use the $_GET superglobal to get the html tag that contains the author id *@id* in order to search it in the database?** 
**Otherwise, how can I adjust the code to pass a javascript variable to php (not by user input) that lets me keep the content already loaded on the page?**

---

#### UPDATES

To make clearer the question, I follow the tips in the comments and I updated my scripts using JSON directly to provide the needed data. 
I also perfom a debug on the js code and it's clear that PHP don't provide any response,in fact ajax calls for authors name fails systematically.
I suppose that occurs because PHP don't receive the data dueto the fact I'm not using the correct syntax probably (in js code or in the php with $_GET or in both) to pass the variable *author* (I also tried `data:'author='+author` treating the JSON object *author* has a string). Anyway I don't understand **what is the correct form to write the variable to pass using the *data* field of ajax().**

---

#### MY SCRIPTS

**JS SCRIPT new_search.js**

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submit").on("tap", function () {
        var item = document.getElementById("search").value;
        var author;
        $.ajax({
            url: "item_query.php",
            type: "GET",
            data: 'item=' + item,
            dataType: "json",
            async:false,
            success: function (items) {
                for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                    $("#items-list").append(
                        '<li class="item">' +
                        '<div class="item-photo-container">' +
                        '<img src=images/item_126.jpg>' +
                        "</div><!--end item-photo-container-->" +
                        '<div class="item-info">' +
                        '<ul>' +
                        '<li><a><h3 class="item-name">' + items[i].title + '</h3></a></li>' +
                        '<li class="auth-name">' + items[i].creator+ '</li>' +
                        '<li>' + items[i].issued + '</li>' +
                        '</ul>' +
                        '</div><!--end item-info-->' +
                        '</li><!--end item-->'
                    );
                }
            }
        });

        $('.item').each(function () {
            author = $(this).find('.auth-name').text();
            if (author == 'undefined')
                $(this).find('.auth-name').text('Unknown');
            else if(author.indexOf(',')!=-1) {
                author='[{"author":"'+author+'"}]';
                author=author.replace(/,/g,'"},{"author":"');
                author = JSON.parse(author);
                console.log(author);
                $.ajax({
                    url: "author_query.php",
                    type: "GET",
                    data: author,
                    dataType: "json",
                    processData: false,
                    success: function (auth_json) {
                        $(this).find('.auth-name').text('');
                        var author_text=' ';
                        for(var i=0;i<auth_json.length;i++)
                            author_text+=auth_json.name+' ';
                        $(this).find('.auth-name').text(author_text);
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        console.log('Error 1');

                    }
                });
            }
            else{
                author='{"author":"'+author+"}";
                author=JSON.parse(author);
                $.ajax({
                    url: "author_query.php",
                    type: "GET",
                    data: author,
                    dataType: "json",
                    processData: false,
                    success: function (auth_json) {
                        $(this).find('.auth-name').text(auth_json.name);
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        console.log('Error 2');

                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**AUTHOR PHP SCRIPT author_query.php**

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$auth=$_GET['author'];
$client = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://localhost:27017");
$db=$client->galileo;
$collection=$db->persons;
if(is_array($auth)){
    foreach ($auth as $a){
        $document=$collection->findOne(['@id'=>$a],['projection'=>['_id'=>0,'name'=>1]]);
        $auth_json[]=( MongoDB\BSON\toJSON(MongoDB\BSON\fromPHP($document)));
    }
}
else{
    $document=$collection->findOne(['@id'=>$auth],['projection'=>['_id'=>0,'name'=>1]]);
    $auth_json=( MongoDB\BSON\toJSON(MongoDB\BSON\fromPHP($document)));
}

echo (json_encode($auth_json));

?>
```

Comment: I’m not sure I understand your issue... `$_GET` is definitely not limited to forms, it’ll contain any of the name=value parameters after the ? in the URL, and that includes stuff sent via Ajax requests.

Comment: Also why are you turning json into a string, doing some weird sub-stringing, and then turning it back into json?  That's a pretty big code smell, imho.

Comment: @Taplar Raises a valid point here. Simply `json_encode($doc)` actually would simply return JSON. If you want a "JSON encoded array", then it's simply converting the "cursor" into a regular array and then calling `json_encode` on that. There is in fact a [`toArray()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb-driver-cursor.toarray.php) method on that `Cursor` returned by `find()`, for exactly that purpose. So you don't need to Coerce to BSON and then to JSON, and you certainly don't need to re-encode such a result. Use a plain array and encode it once.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thanks, and thanks also to Taplar to underline the bad section of code. I'll fix this point, I'm new to MongoDB and I don't know the whole potentiality of the library yet.

Comment: @jcaron My fault, I misunderstood an article I read. Anyway, debugging the js code I see that in nested ajax call fails (the success function is not performed) and I'm sure that authors array( filled in the while method in a beginner way ,I admit) is not empty and actually contains the authors IDs. So, I imagine my error is in  *how* I use $_GET  or in *what* I wrote in the data field of ajax call, but I can't find it.

Comment: "in nested ajax call fails (the success function is not performed)" But is the error function called? If so, what arguments does it receive? `error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { console.log('Error 2', jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown); }`

Comment: I don't know that much PHP, but I think that as it stands, `$auth` will be a JSON string. Not an array. It will look like `'{"author":"author1"}'`, or else `'[{"author":"author1"},{"author":"author2"}]'`; PHP is expecting `'author1'` or `['author1','author2']`. This means that `$collection->findOne` will fail to find any rows in the database. I'm guessing that makes it throw an exception. You need to pick a string format; it doesn't matter which one. Oh, and don't treat a singleton array as a special case, it just makes extra work. There's nothing wrong with `['author1']`.

Answer (score 0):

"I'm sure that authors array... is not empty and actually contains the authors IDs". You mean the jQuery object `$('.item')`? I think that it is empty, because it is created too soon.

The first `$.ajax` call sends an ajax request and sets a handler to add more stuff to the HTML, including elements that will match the CSS selector `.item`. But the handler doesn't run yet because it's asynchronous. Immediately after this, the object `$('.item')` is created, but it's empty because the new `.item` elements haven't been created yet. So no more ajax requests are sent. Some time later, the call to `item_query.php` returns, and the new HTML stuff is added, including the `.item` elements. But by now it's too late.

You say the array was not empty. I suspect you checked this by running the CSS selector after doing the search, after the return of the ajax call.

A lot of newbies have problems like this with asynchronous javascript. If you want to use the result of an asynchronous function in another function, you have to call the second function inside the callback function of the first one. (Actually there are more sophisticated ways of combining asynchronous functions together, but this is good enough for now.)

On a side note, you've done this in a slightly strange way where you save data in HTML, and then read the HTML to do some more stuff. I wouldn't use HTML as a storage place - just use variables like you would for most other things.

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "item_query.php",
    ...
    success: function (items) {
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            var author = items[i].creator;
            var authors;
            // insert code here to generate authors from author.split(',') . 
            // authors should look something like this: [{author: 'http://minerva.atcult.it/rdf/47734211-2637-3895-a690-4f33412931ec'}] .
            $.ajax({
                url: "author_query.php",
                type: "GET",
                data: JSON.stringify(authors),
                ...
                success: function (auth_json) {
                    ...
                },
                error: function () {
                    console.log('Error 1');
                }
            });

            $("#items-list").append(
                '<li class="item">' +
                '<div class="item-photo-container">' +
                '<img src=images/item_126.jpg>' +
                "</div><!--end item-photo-container-->" +
                '<div class="item-info">' +
                '<ul>' +
                '<li><a><h3 class="item-name">' + items[i].title + '</h3></a></li>' +
                '<li class="auth-name">' + items[i].creator+ '</li>' +
                '<li>' + items[i].issued + '</li>' +
                '</ul>' +
                '</div><!--end item-info-->' +
                '</li><!--end item-->'
            );
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: The first ajax call is asynchronous even if I declared `async:false `?

Comment: My mistake, I didn't see that part. (But also, don't do synchronous ajax calls.)

Answer (score 0):

I make the first call to retrieve the item infos **asynchronous** and the nested that search for the authors name **synchronous**. In this way I solved the problem.
For sure it is not the best solution, and it needs a quite long,but acceptable, time (<1 second) to load the content.

#### JS SCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submit").on("tap", function () {
        var item = document.getElementById("search").value;
        $.ajax({
            url: "item_query.php",
            type: "GET",
            data: 'item=' + item,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (items) {
                for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                        var authors_names=' ';
                        var authors= JSON.stringify(items[i]);
                        if(authors.indexOf('creator')!=-1){
                            if(authors.charAt(authors.indexOf('"creator":')+'"creator":'.length)!='[')
                                authors=authors.substring(authors.indexOf('"creator":"'),authors.indexOf('"',authors.indexOf('"creator":"')+'"creator":"'.length)+1);
                            else
                                authors=authors.substring(authors.indexOf('"creator"'),authors.indexOf(']',authors.indexOf('"creator"'))+1);
                            authors='{'+authors+'}';
                            //console.log(authors);
                            $.ajax({
                                url: "author_query_v3.php",
                                type: "GET",
                                data: 'authors='+authors,
                                dataType:"json",
                                async:false,
                                success: function (auth_json) {
                                    authors=[];
                                    authors=auth_json;
                                    var author;
                                    for(var j=0;j<authors.length;j++){
                                        author=JSON.parse(authors[j]);
                                        authors_names+=author.name+" | ";
                                    }

                                    console.log(authors_names);
                                },
                                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                    console.log(jqXHR+' '+textStatus+ ' '+errorThrown);
                                }
                            });



                        }
                        else{
                            authors_names='Unknown';
                        }


                    $("#items-list").append(
                        '<li class="item">' +
                        '<div class="item-photo-container">' +
                        '<img src=images/item_126.jpg>' +
                        "</div><!--end item-photo-container-->" +
                        '<div class="item-info">' +
                        '<ul>' +
                        '<li><a><h3 class="item-name">' + items[i].title + '</h3></a></li>' +
                        '<li class="auth-name">' + authors_names+ '</li>' +
                        '<li>' + items[i].issued + '</li>' +
                        '</ul>' +
                        '</div><!--end item-info-->' +
                        '</li><!--end item-->'
                    );



                }

            }
        });
    });
  });
```

#### PHP SCRIPT

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$auth=$_GET['authors'];
$client = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://localhost:27017");
$db=$client->galileo;
$collection=$db->persons;
$auth=json_decode($auth);
$auth=$auth->creator;
if(is_array($auth)) {
    foreach ($auth as $a) {
        $document = $collection->findOne(['@id' => $a], ['projection' => ['_id' => 0, 'name' => 1]]);
        $auth_json[] = (MongoDB\BSON\toJSON(MongoDB\BSON\fromPHP($document)));
    }
}
else{
    $document=$collection->findOne(['@id'=>$auth],['projection'=>['_id'=>0,'name'=>1]]);
    $auth_json[]=( MongoDB\BSON\toJSON(MongoDB\BSON\fromPHP($document)));
}
echo(json_encode($auth_json));
?>
```